# Lookup column of type "User" showing #ERR

Tags: development, lookup-column, custom, list-definition

I've defined two list definitions and instances in a feature in VS2010.

One list only contains a required field "Employee" which is of type User.

The second list has two fields, a simple text field and a lookup field to the first list. Here's the field definition from the Schema.xml

```
<Field ID="{DC591BA2-D262-4810-B697-BE2E6AF64226}" Name="UserLookup" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE"  DisplayName="Employee" Type="Lookup" Required="TRUE" List="Lists/User" ShowField="EmployeeName" Indexed="TRUE"></Field>
```

This works fine, and when I use new or edit forms, I get the names of the values in the first list. But in the view, the value is #ERR instead of the name. I changed it to ID and that shows fine, but the name won't show - anyone got any ideas?

Relevant schema.xml from the first list:

```
<ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x01006ffb64509c2341d2bff13b98859f792b" Name="User" Description="" Inherits="FALSE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          <RemoveFieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" />
          <FieldRef ID="{97666FB8-EF69-4063-924F-06E459383B7D}" Name="EmployeeName" Required="TRUE"></FieldRef>
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{97666FB8-EF69-4063-924F-06E459383B7D}" Indexed="TRUE" Name="EmployeeName" DisplayName="Employee" Type="User" Required="TRUE"></Field>
    </Fields>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using People and group column which cannot be made as a look up column in another list.

You may use a text field to do the lookup by creating a text field in the first list, and set the value to user and group field name.

Then you can use the field you created as lookup to another list.